# Can only start VNC sessions with sudo

Tags: centos, x11, vnc

I'm trying to start a VNC session on a remove CentOS 7.3 VM and access it, but for some reason I'm only able to make it work by running `sudo vncserver` and not just `vncserver`. When I run it as myself, connecting produces the image below. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[Gist with VNC log.](https://gist.github.com/Aidoboy/fe7780b9b453f966f3a651be5ee6f1a7)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you include your `~/.vnc/xstartup` file? it looks like the chosen session is failing to start because it requires a 3d acceleration capability that tightvncserver is unable to support (I don't know why it should be different with `sudo` though - unless sudo is effectively `sudo -H` and root has a different VNC session).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out it was something weird to do with the way I was doing X forwarding and setting environment variables in PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

Normally vncserver runs as root and is started with
service vncserver start
running as running as root
or automatically started during system startup.
vncserver lets other users log in as well, but running it as one user would prevent that.

Comment: The way I've been using VNC is logging in with ssh and running `vncserver -depth 16 -geometry 1920x1200`

Comment: Also, I'm the only one using this VM, so I don't mind not allowing other people to use VNC on it.